# How to set a timer for a specific time

Tags: javascript, html

I need to set a timer for a specific time?

I have two inputs 1st one is the arrival time and 2nd one is the departure time, if the different between these two for example is 1:20 (one hour and 20 minutes) the timer start and countdown the time and before the time finished (10 minutes before) it must give an alert that the is about to finish after 10 minutes.

and also can how to show this output of these two dates automatically without clicking on calculate button?

[image: screenshot]

below is my code:

```
<html>
<body>
<form id="calculate" action=""> 
<div> 
           <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="departure"><strong>Arrival Time </strong></label>
              <?php $date = date("H:i"); ?>
             <input type="time" name="hour_start" value="<?= $date ?>">
         </div> 
    <br />
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
         <label for="departure"><strong>Departure Time</strong></label>
          <?php $date = date("H:i"); ?>
         <input type="time" name="hour_end" value="<?= $date ?>">
    </div>

     <p id="diff_hour"></p>

    <p><input id="calculate_time" type="button" value="Calculate Time" /></p>
</div> 
</form>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function showTime(hours, minutes) {
    return ((hours < 10) ? '0' : '') + hours +
        ':' +
        ((minutes < 10) ? '0' : '') + minutes;
}
function calculate_time(hour_start, hour_end) {
    startTime = new Date('1-1-1 ' + hour_start);
    endTime = new Date('1-1-1 ' + hour_end);

    var difference = endTime - startTime;
    difference /= 1000 * 60; 
    var hours = Math.floor(difference / 60);
    var mins = Math.floor(difference % 60);
    document.getElementById('diff_hour').innerHTML = showTime(hours, mins);
}
document.getElementById('calculate_time').onclick = function () {
    var start = this.form.elements.hour_start.value;
    var end = this.form.elements.hour_end.value;
    calculate_time(start, end);
};

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As you are using PHP to generate and write the dates into the various HTML form fields you can calculate the difference in PHP also and assign that as a javascript variable which is used in the timer script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you calculate the time, you can use that time and subtract 10 minutes from the calculated time. Then use setTimeout to trigger the notification.

```
const notifyTime = (time.hours * 60 * 60 * 1000) + (time.minutes * 60 * 1000) - (10 * 60* 1000);

  if (notifyTime > 0) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('get ready')
    }, notifyTime)
  }
```

EDIT: Updated code. You have to listen for the change event on the 2nd input to get the time and then recalculate time and run the timer.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
  function showTime(hours, minutes) {
    return ((hours < 10) ? '0' : '') + hours +
      ':' +
      ((minutes < 10) ? '0' : '') + minutes;
  }

  function calculate_time(hour_start, hour_end) {
    startTime = new Date('1-1-1 ' + hour_start);
    endTime = new Date('1-1-1 ' + hour_end);

    var difference = endTime - startTime;
    difference /= 1000 * 60;
    var hours = Math.floor(difference / 60);
    var mins = Math.floor(difference % 60);
    return {
      hours: hours,
      minutes: mins
    };
  }

  var timer = null;

  function getTimeDifference() {
    var start = document.getElementById('startTime').value;
    var end = document.getElementById('endTime').value;
    const time = calculate_time(start, end);
    document.getElementById('diff_hour').innerHTML = showTime(time.hours, time.minutes)

    // convert to miliseconds and subtract 10minutes to get notified
    const notifyTime = (time.hours * 60 * 60 * 1000) + (time.minutes * 60 * 1000) - (10 * 60 * 1000);

    clearTimeout(timer)

    if (notifyTime > 0) {
      timer = setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('get ready')
        clearTimeout(timer)
      }, notifyTime)
    }
  }

  getTimeDifference();

  document.getElementById('endTime').addEventListener('change', function() {
    getTimeDifference()
  });
})
```

```html
<form id="calculate" action="">
  <div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="departure"><strong>Arrival Time </strong></label>
      <?php $date = date("H:i"); ?>
      <input id="startTime" type="time" name="hour_start" value="01:00">
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="departure"><strong>Departure Time</strong></label>
      <?php $date = date("H:i"); ?>
      <input id="endTime" type="time" name="hour_end" value="01:11">
    </div>

    <p id="diff_hour"></p>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: for the above example to test, you can set the start and end time to be 11 minutes apart and click on `Calculate Time` button.

Comment: Thank you so much Mr. SpiritOfDragon, Can you help here more? How to get the output of the these two inputs automatically without this button, I need the different appears by changing the second input value.

Comment: Can you explain a bit here? Will the inputs be filled when the page loads?

Comment: Yes both inputs fill when the page loads (same time in both inputs), but I am going to change the second input (the hour and minute) and after that the difference must be appear without any button to be clicked.

Comment: You can assign `event listeners` to the time input elements

Comment: @Sofia I have updated the code snippet. please check it out. accept the answer if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a little play around and offer this as a possible solution. I expanded upon the original a little and factored in the ability to modify the period before the departure time that the timer is set to activate upon.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
  var gt=NaN; //global timer variable.


  const STATUS={
    COMPLETE:"Timer expired....Let's get ready to rumble!",
    INVALID:"The 'End' time cannot be before the 'Start' time"
  }


  function showTime(h,m) {
    return [ pad( h ), pad( m ) ].join(':')
  };
  const pad=function(i){
    return i < 10 ? '0' + i : i;
  };
  const convert=function(e,s){
    let d=e-s;
      d/=( 1000 * 60 );
    let h=Math.floor( d / 60 );
    let m=Math.floor( d % 60 );
    return { 'h':h, 'm':m };
  };
  const setsamevalue=function(e){
    /*
      utility to set the value of the other
      time input field to the value of the currently active
      if there is an invalid entry
    */
    let other=document.querySelector('input[ type="time" ]:not( [ name="'+e.target.getAttribute('name')+'" ] )');
      e.target.value=other.value;

    alert( STATUS.INVALID );
    return false;
  };


  function calculate_time(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    //DOM elements and form values
    const countdown=document.getElementById('countdown');
    const display=document.getElementById('diff_hour');
    const warning=document.querySelector( 'input[type="number"][name="warning"]' ).value

    let hstart=document.querySelector( 'input[type="time"][name="hour_start"]' ).value;
    let hend=document.querySelector( 'input[type="time"][name="hour_end"]' ).value;

    //ensure timer variable is cancelled on each invocation
    if( !isNaN( gt ) )clearTimeout( gt );


    //convert values from form inputs to Date objects
    let start=new Date();
      start.setHours( hstart.split(':')[0] );
      start.setMinutes( hstart.split(':')[1] );

    let end=new Date();
      end.setHours( hend.split(':')[0] );
      end.setMinutes( hend.split(':')[1] );

    // cannot proceed if the end time is before start time
    if( end <= start ) return setsamevalue(e);


    // initialise the warning at this date/time
    // this is the end time - X minutes
    let warn=new Date();
      warn.setTime( end.getTime() - ( warning * 1000 * 60 ) );

    // variable to pass to the timer function
    // this is the number of seconds from the start until the timer should expire.
    let duration=( warn.getTime() - start.getTime() ) / 1000;

    // calculate and display time difference
    let o=convert( end, start );
    display.innerHTML = showTime( o.h, o.m );




    // the countdown timer function
    (function( t ){
      (function(){
        if( t <= 0 ){
          clearTimeout( gt );
          countdown.textContent=STATUS.COMPLETE;
          countdown.classList.add('expired');
          return false;
        }
        countdown.textContent=[ parseInt(t), 's' ].join('');
        gt=setTimeout( arguments.callee, 1000 );
        t--;
      })()
    })( duration );
  };




  Array.from( document.querySelectorAll('input[type="time"]') ).forEach( el=>{
    el.addEventListener('change', calculate_time )
  });

  document.getElementById('initialise').addEventListener('click', calculate_time );
});
```

```css
body,body *{
  font-family:monospace;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
#calculate{
  width:80%;
  margin:1rem auto;
  float:none;
  padding:1rem;border:1px solid black;
}
#diff_hour:before{
  content:'Time difference = '
}
#countdown:before{
  content:'Time left before warning = ';
}
.form-group input{
  float:right
}
.expired{color:red}
.expired:before{content:''!important;}

input{width:15%}
```

```html
<form id='calculate'> 
  <div>
    <div class='form-group col-md-4'>
      <label for='departure'><strong>Arrival Time</strong></label>
      <input type='time' name='hour_start' value='13:37' />
    </div>

    <br />

    <div class='form-group col-md-4'>
      <label for='departure'><strong>Departure Time</strong></label>
      <input type='time' name='hour_end' value='15:07' />
    </div>

    <br />

    <div class='form-group col-md-4'>
      <label for='warning'><strong>Warning Time</strong></label>
      <input type='number' name='warning' min=1 max=60 step=1 value='10' title='The warning will be given this value BEFORE the departure time' />
    </div>

    <br />

    <div>
      <p id='diff_hour'>01:30</p>
      <div id='countdown'>1200s</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>Simply changing either of the time values will initialise the countdown timer... or you could <a id='initialise' href='#'>click here</a></p>
</form>
```